# Eclipse: How to connect to SVN repository? Or how to enter username and password?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have a problem connecting to a SVN repository in Eclipse (Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)), because I cannot enter a username and a password and and I can not find a way to do that.

At first right click and "add a new SVN repository". Here i can only enter a URL. Earlier it was possible to enter username and password directly here:

[image]

Then the error message appears, but it´s clear because I have not entered any access data:
[image]

Anyway I can see the repository now and earlier it was possible with right click and then "location repository" to change username and password, but there is no entry "location repository":
[image]

Additionally I deleted the svn.simple file but that didn't work either under c:\Documents and Settings[username]\Application Data\subversion\auth\svn.simple

I have searched all over eclipse for a way to enter username and password, but unfortunately I found nothing. I am desperate and hope that someone can help me. :)

Thanks and best regards
Benni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong plugin installed. It was subclipse installed. I uninstalled it and installed subversion. Now everything works and I can enter username and password. :) Sorry for wasting your time...